# How to prove that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that both $n!+1,n!-1$ are composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

According to [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) if $p$ is a prime number we have $p\mid (p-1)!+1$ so if we prove that for infinitely many prime numbers $p$, $(p-1)!-1$ is composite we're done.

Since $p-1=-1 \pmod p$  and $(p-1)!=-1\pmod p$  we can conclude that $(p-2)!=1\pmod p$  so if we prove that for infinitely many prime numbers $p$,$(p-2)!+1$ is composite we're also done.

So if we consider that for sufficiently large prime numbers $p$,  both $(p-1)!-1$ and $(p-2)!+1$ are prime numbers and have a contradiction with this suppose the problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: @Mohammadreza Welcome to Math SE. FYI, you're basically asking about values which are not [Factorial primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime). Also, a fairly similar question from about a day ago is [Is there integer $n>3$ such that both $n!-1$ and $n!+1$ are prime?](/q/4469502/602049), and an earlier fairly similar question is [Is either $n! + 1$ or $n! - 1$ not prime for all $n$?](/q/3809973/602049).

Comment: In your proof, the primes $p$ which divide $(p-1)!-1$ are different from the primes $p$ which divide $(p-1)!+1$ (of course, otherwise $p$ would divide their difference, which is $2$). But you want to find integers $n$ which *simultaneously* divide $(n-1)!-1$ and $(n-1)+1$.

Comment: It seems obvious that this must be the case since the primes of the form $n!-1$ or $n!+1$ dramatically thin out. Nevertheless I think that we cannot prove it.

Comment: The last part is confusing. Even if there were infinite many primes $p$ such that $(p-1)!-1$ and $(p-2)!+1$ are both prime (and we could prove this) , we would still not have solved the conjecture , neither in the positive nor in the negative sense.